# PdfLaTeX is working fine and tex4ht is not working and showing error

Tags: pdftex, tex4ht

The below simple equations are working fine in **PdfLaTeX** and not working in fine **htlatex**.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{article}
\def\a{\alpha}
\begin{document}
Test $\varphi_{\a}$, $\varphi_1$
\end{document}
```

How to solve this error. My main goal is whatever working in PdfLaTeX the same LaTeX document it's should be working in "tex4ht".

My version is : tex4ht.c (2018-07-03-10:36 Windows MiKTeX)

How to solve this problem.

Comment: `\a` is already defined, it is an accent, and if you redefine it to something unrelated without adjusting the tex4ht configuration too, tex4ht will break. So don't use `\def` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @Ulrike: Now i got idea and it's working fine. Could you post this answer so that i will accept for the future purpose.